# Incorporating Simple-Facebook but get error

Tags: android, android-simple-facebook

I am trying to use Simple-Facebook. Everything looks great and i have no errors....until i run it....

Then i get this error

Add reference from Simple Facebook project to FacebookSDK project.

It says that something is wrong here

```
     @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        APP_ID = getString(R.string.facebook_app_id);

        // set log to true
        //Logger.DEBUG_WITH_STACKTRACE = true;

        // initialize facebook configuration
        Permission[] permissions = new Permission[] {
                Permission.PUBLIC_PROFILE,
                Permission.PUBLISH_ACTION,

                Permission.PUBLIC_PROFILE
        };

        SimpleFacebookConfiguration configuration = new SimpleFacebookConfiguration.Builder()
                .setAppId(APP_ID)
                .setNamespace(APP_NAMESPACE)
                .setPermissions(permissions)
             //   .setDefaultAudience()
                .setAskForAllPermissionsAtOnce(false)
                .build();

        SimpleFacebook.setConfiguration(configuration);

       // Utils.printHashKey(this);
    }


}
```

I have absolutely no idea what to do...I saw somewhere that it does this if you dont have the FaceBook SDK imported.... but i believe i do. I am able to access all of the facebook buttons like "LoginButton" and so on... PLEASE HELP

Comment: Did you add uses library FacebookSdk in your project...?

Comment: how do i do that?  i dont believe i did @user4728480